# When Batch Sending Events in Azure Event Hubs how can you calculate the total message size?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have this problem where I am reading messages from SQL server (data could vary some fields are varchar(max)) and batch sending them by serializing them to JSON Azure Event Hubs Batch sending mechanism has a limit of 250Kb, is there a easy to check the size of the list of eventdata that gets trasmitted before the submission? Most of the times the data is tiny so I would want to batch up several messages. How can I know what size will the payload is going to be. I really don't want to count characters and calculate the size and thinking there is a better way you guys can help with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .NET SDK `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`, you can use `Serialized​Size​In​Bytes` property [(see docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.serializedsizeinbytes?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData_SerializedSizeInBytes). Then sum them up for the batch.

Unfortunately, I don't see it in the new [Azure Event Hubs Client for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet).

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryAdd function available in EventHub SDK.

[Event Hub Data batch - TryAdd (EventData data)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventdatabatch.tryadd?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventDataBatch_TryAdd_Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventData_)